# ImportError: win32 only when deploying a django app on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, importerror

**The error :**

from asyncio.windows_events import NULL
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/asyncio/windows_events.py", line 6, in 
raise ImportError('win32 only')
ImportError: win32 only

**please how can i fix this ?**

Comment: did you write win32 in requirements.txt?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: No i didn't add win32 to requirements.txt .... should i ?

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error while trying to deploy:

```
File "/tmp/build_4a1c8563/base/models.py", line 1, in <module>
       from asyncio.windows_events import NULL
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/asyncio/windows_events.py", line 6, in <module>
       raise ImportError('win32 only')
```

I deleted the "from asyncio.windows_events import NULL" in models.py and the issue was solved. Wasn't event using that module...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error while deploying:

your IDE have imported `from asyncio.windows_events import NULL` line automatically while you were typing NULL

Just delete this line

```
from asyncio.windows_events import NULL
```

Comment: This is the same solution as the one already provided in the other answer. The idea about where the line may have come from can be added in a comment to that answer.